# Mvc route is not taking default values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomRoute",
            url: "{country}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
        );
```

but i only can acces to my CustomRoute with something like /ES/es/Test/Action if I try with something like /ES/es/ I have 404 error, it doesn´t find the page, and I really need the /ES/es/ way. Some ideas why is not taking default values in CustomRoute ? ... thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you create another question?

Comment: @vonv. i thought i was something stressful for you, i was a little ashamed

Comment: No need to be ashamed, people are here to help out one another and to build a great wiki-site with rich content. So is your problem solved? at all? If yes then you can delete this one if it serves no purpose and if "it's really a duplicate".

Comment: @vonv. i solved a part of my problem with your help, but now i have this new issue, its not solved at all, i think it can serve for one other. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see sample code:

```
 //routes.MapRoute(
 //    "Default", // Route name
 //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
 //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 //);

   routes.MapRoute(
        "CustomRoute", // Route name
        "{country}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { country = "MyContry", lang = "Mylanguage", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this links, hope this could help you..

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6543/custom-route-for-writing-friendly-urls-in-asp-net-mvc-3

http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much, there are really interesting links, and i now they are going to help a lot, but im still getting my problem.